# Laravel Creating relationship while updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a library management system with Student and Book model. The structure of the tables are

Students Table

```
id | roll_no | name | created_at | updated_at
```

Books Table

```
book_id | name | author | publication | student_id | created_at | updated_at
```

Here, `boook_id` is the primary key

#### The relation is as follows

In Book Model

```
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Student');
}
```

In Student Model

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
}
```

Initially the `student_id` in books table is `null`. Whenever a book is to be issued, `book number` and student `roll number` is supplied and the `student_id` field in books table is updated with the `id` of the student to whom it is being issued.

In the controller, I have the following code

```
public function postIssue(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [ 
        'rollno' => 'required|min:7',
        'bookno' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);
    $roll = $request->input('rollno');
    $bookno = $request->input('bookno');

    $student = Student::where('roll_no','=',$roll);
    $book = Book::where('book_id','=',$bookno);
    $book->student_id = $student->id;
    $book->save();
    
    return view('book.issue')->with('msg','Book Issued');
}
```

When I run this codes, I get a error saying
`"Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$id"`

What is going wrong?
Is there a better way of doing this?

I am using Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$student = Student::where('roll_no','=',$roll)->first();
$book = Book::where('book_id','=',$bookno)->first();
```

change like this way hope it will work .